# How to edit CupertinoSegmentedControl?

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino

I want to change this.

[image]

to this with flutter. but I have no idea how?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my solution was to use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/animated_segmented_tab_control with a custom radius applied to make the Segments rounded.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the too late answer, but use CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl can solve your problem
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08WOe.png)